# sitemap.xml URL is not getting redirected to new URL

Tags: xml, magento, magento2

I have a sitemap.xml file generated in magento2 on localhost. Following is the link http://magento.local/sitemap.xml
Now i want to redirect above URL to http://magento.local/pub/sitemap.xml using URL rewrite. I have created URL Rewrite as
[shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgVql.png)

But http://magento.local/sitemap.xml URL is not getting redirected http://magento.local/pub/sitemap.xml. But if I delete original sitemap.xml file it gets redirected to new URL. Is there any way I can redirect it without deleting existing sitemap.xml?

Another option
I added the following rule to .htaccess file and it works fine on local, but on server it fails. URL is not getting redirected

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect 301 /sitemap.xml  http://magento.local/pub/sitemap.xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added the following rule to .htaccess file and it works fine on local, but on server it does not work
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
 Redirect 301 /sitemap.xml  http://magento.local/pub/sitemap.xml
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

According to [URL Rewrites](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html)

> The URL Rewrite tool lets you change any URL that is associated with a
> product, category, or CMS page.

I believe your sitemap.xml is a physical file which is locate on the disk, then it won't work with Url Rewrite. When you delete the original file, server will try to consider the URL as a page. You can do the redirection using nginx rewrite rule, refer [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Answer (score 0):

In your htaccess file you need to paste this code. It works for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://magento.local$

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml http://magento.local/pub/sitemap.xml
```